# MongoDB update causes other unmatched filed to be updated too

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am doing a restaurant management system, at the table ordering section, there are list of table with ID label on it *(eg. T01, T02...)*, when I click on one of the table, there will be modal pop up with food menu, which I can click to add quantity of any food or reduce it.

## PROBLEM

When I try to add quantity of any food while **ordering many tables**, the other tables also **got the quantity that I added to current table**.

If `Table1: {Fish : 3}, Table2: {Fish : 0}`, if I add 1 quantity of Fish to Table2, Table1 also be added by 1

Final Result: `Table1: {Fish : 4}, Table2: {Fish : 1}`

## Trigger

If I order for Table1, then close the modal and back to order section to order for Table2, Table1 will be affected, this goes on if I order for N tables, all tables will be affected

## Temporary-Solution

If I order for Table1, then refresh the browser, then order for Table2, then the previous table that I ordered does not get affect by it

I'm using Meteor 1.4

## Code:

```
//Client
'click .js-order' : (e) => {
  var tableId = e.currentTarget.id;

  var findTableOrder = Order.findOne({table_id: tableId});

  var orderList = {}

  findTableOrder
    ? console.log("Order exist")
    : Order.insert({table_id: tableId, order: orderList});

  orderList = Order.findOne({table_id: tableId}).order

  Session.set("quantityTrack", orderList);
  $("#orderModal").modal("show");

  $(".modal-title").text("Order for table: " + Tables.findOne({_id: tableId}).table_id);

  $(".js-add-quantity").click((e) => { // Adding Event
    var foodObjKey = ItemMeta.findOne({UID: e.currentTarget.id}).foodId;
    if (orderList[foodObjKey] == null) {
      orderList[foodObjKey] = 0;
    }
    orderList[foodObjKey] = orderList[foodObjKey] + 1;
    Meteor.call("updateOrder", tableId, orderList, (err) => {
      err
        ? console.log(err)
        : console.log("Order Update Successful");
    });
    Session.set("quantityTrack", orderList);
  }); // Adding event ends
}

//Server/methods
updateOrder : (tableid, orderlist) => {
  Order.update({
    table_id: tableid
  }, {
    $set: {
      order: orderlist
    }
  });
});
```

If I missed anything, please tell me and I will edit the post, and thanks very much beforehand.

Comment: `console.log(e.currentTarget.id)` to debug and make sure the `table_id`'s are unique for each table

Comment: @jonathan, yes i already console log to see it, but because i dont want to have my code to appear messy when asking question so i remove them here. The table_id are all unique for each table, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of template helpers is there always waiting to listen for event, if an event is triggered, it add, so after clicked on an table, it waits, and clicking on another table, triggered both table to be added, so the solution is separate the adding event out of the same click event of table.